# Прикрепление файлов по QR-коду со смартфона

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, html5

Есть такой вопрос, на сайте есть форма загрузки файла, возможно ли сделать добавление/прикрепление файла к форме на сайт по QR коду(ссылке) из смартфона. Если можно, то как отслеживать загрузку файла?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что то типа такого

1. Приложением смартфона для чтения QR-кодов сканируется QR-код и получаем ссылку для прикрепления файла на мобильном устройстве.
2. Переходим по ссылке и выбраем файл из галереи или фото с камеры смартфона.
3. Файл загружается и прикрепляется на десктопе.

Comment: Что? Ничего не понятно!

Comment: Добавлено описание к вопросу, надеюсь сейчас более понятно, что хочется получить)

Comment: Ну, я могу себе представить теоретически как это сделать. Но не могу представить зачем городить такие сложности. Наверняка есть куча других способов решить задачу, если вы расскажете в чём она заключается. Например банально открыть сайт на телефоне.

Comment: Хотелось бы узнать теорию, тоже представляю как примерно это сделать, не представляю как отслеживать загрузку файла с другого девайса.

Почему городить такие сложности - веб приложение грубо говоря не имеет мобильной версии, а хочется пользователю дать возможность загрузить файлы с телефона (возможность загрузки с файлов с облачных сервисов реализована).

Comment: Вот ищу способы выйти из положения) Спасибо за любую теорию и помощь)

Comment: ну зашифруйте всю заполненную форму в qr, добавьте туда некий флаг и по его наличию скриптом активируйте поле загрузки файла. форму из qr расшифровать, файл прицепить и отправить на сервер

Answer (score 0):

Готового решения не будет :)

Общая идея - грузите файл с телефона, на десктопе показываете прогресс.

Один из способов, как можно сделать.

1. На сервере поднимаете webscocket (можете и через ajax опросы сервера).
2. В qr код пишите ссылку на загрузку файла
3. Грузите файл на телефоне, на сервере куда-то записываете прогресс\отправляете по вебсокету
4. На десктопе слушаете вебсокет(или ajax опросы сервера) - показываете прогресс.

Comment: Готовое решение не жду)
Спасибо за подсказку, попробую

Comment: @Walle если ответ вам помог, можете принять его как правильный.